# Call a function when a user grants camera permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How do I call a function once a user grants camera or location permission?

I thought of using a while loop, but that doesn't like an elegant solution. I know I can check the permission status ("Authorized", "Undetermined", etc.), but it doesn't let me know if the user has granted permission.

Is there a way to be immediately notified?

Comment: `CLLocationManger` has a delegate method that is fired when the location permissions change.  The os kills your app when the camera permission changes so being notified wouldn't really be useful.

Comment: @dan iOS only kills an app if the user changes the permission through Settings. If iOS prompts the user the first time and the user makes a choice, the app is not killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check the current permission. If it's unknown, you can make a request for permission and get notified what the user chooses.

Something like this will work for camera permission:

```
AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
switch (status) {
    case AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
        // User accepted permission in the past - take a picture
        break;
    case AVAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        // User denied permission in the past - handle as needed
        break;
    case AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        // Restrictions prevent access to the camera - handle as needed
        break;
    case AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            if (granted) {
                // User just gave permission - take a picture
            } else {
                // User just denied permission - don't take a picture
            }
        }];
        break;
}
```

The code for location permission will be similar.

Comment: @Cesare - did something change? I noticed you unaccepted the answer.